# Create all combinations of two vectors in R?

Tags: r, missing-data, panel-data

I have a dataframe with Prices indexed according to Date, State, and Product Code.

However, some of the data is missing. I want a data point for every possible combination of Date, State, and Product Code.

(By the way, my Date vector is an integer from 200601 to 201212.)

The way I would like to do this is, for each missing Price, take the Price for the same UPC in the same State at the nearest Date.

Let's say the Price is missing for Product A in State 1 for 200803. I would like to create an algorithm that looks for a price for Product A in State 1 for 200804, then for 200802, then for 200805, etc. etc. until it finds a Price. I only want an NA if there is no Price in that Product for that State at all.

Does anyone know how to do this? I imagine there is a package that will do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `expand.grid` to get all the combinations of the `unique` values in the three columns.  Then, use `merge` with `all.x=TRUE` to merge with the initial dataset.

```
 df2 <- expand.grid(lapply(df1[c('Date', 'State', 
                  'Product Code')], unique))
 merge(df2, df1, by = c('Date', 'State', 'Product Code'),
             all.x=TRUE)
```